# Compute conditional probabilities of dependent events

Tags: probability, statistics

We are given an outcome *A* and a three different events $E_{1}$, $E_{2}$ and $E_{3}$, $E_{4}$. All the events are mutually dependent.

Now, we would like to compute:

$P(A|E_1, E_2, E_3, E_4)$

Is there a way to compute this using joint probabilities? How would you express it using conditional probabilities?

Comment: "Now, we would like to compute:" ... why?  Those expressions don't seem very meaningful.  What is the motivation?

Comment: @GrahamKemp When rewriting the question I realized that I was just overcomplicating things. I think I have an answer already, but I edited the question to double check. Hope this time is more clear :)

Comment: "...three different events $E_1,E_2$ and $E_3,E_4$." [I'll come in again.](http://www.montypython.net/scripts/spanish.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition of conditional probability: $\mathsf P(A\mid E_1,E_2,E_3,E_4)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(A,E_1,E_2,E_3,E_4)}{\mathsf P(E_1,E_2,E_3,E_4)}$

And of course, $\mathsf P(E_1,E_2,E_3,E_4)=\mathsf P(A,E_1,E_2,E_3,E_4)+\mathsf P(A^\complement,E_1,E_2,E_3,E_4)$

And so on.

Comment: Just like It though. Thank you though, having to rewrite the initial question actually helped a lot. Question solved.